# Jetpack Compose Correct syntax for compose list state declaration

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, state

If I have a compose function with a list of items as an argument, what is the proper way of creating a state for this list?
By writing this:

```
fun Component(menuItems: List<Item>){
...
    var list by remember {
            mutableStateOf(menuItems)
        }
...
}
```

I get empty list.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "creating a state for this".  Do you want to alter the values in the list, or keep track of which one is selected for UX purposes?

Comment: In production code I usually have the data defined as a StateFlow in the viewmodel, and then use `collectAsState()` in the composable.  Once the viewmodel populates the data, it will show up in the composable.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an empty list because this is probably the first time your function `Component` has been called with an empty list as a parameter.
So if you want the value of the `list` variable to be updated when the list from the function parameters is updated - you need to replace this:

```
var list by remember {
      mutableStateOf(menuItems)
}
```

with this:

```
// use menuItems as a `key` for `remember`
var list by remember(menuItems) {
      mutableStateOf(menuItems) // or mutableStateListOf(menuItems)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the parameters passed to a composable changes, the Composable is recomposed.
So you can use the list directly to create the UI elements.

You don't have to create a state using it unless you need to perform some actions using it.

> Recomposition starts whenever Compose thinks that the parameters of a composable might have changed.

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model#optimistic)

---

---

Examples of scenarios where you may want to create a state using the list and perform some actions.

List actions like - Filtering, mapping, etc.

```
fun Component(menuItems: List<Item>){
    vay searchQuery by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    var list by remember(menuItems, searchQuery) {
        mutableStateOf(
            menuItems
                .filter { it.text.contains(searchQuery.text) }
                .map {
                    MyListItem(it)
                }
        )
    }
}
```